# Is it correct to use "always" in front of a sentence?

Tags: grammaticality, usage

Which one is correct?

> 1. They are always scolded for their bad behaviour.
> 2. Always, they are scolded for their bad behaviour.

Which one is the usual way a native speaker uses?

Answer (score 1):

The first one is definitely more natural. I would say, "They are always being/getting scolded for their bad behaviour."